# Unable to process POST Data and process imaging uploading process

Tags: php, post, file-upload

Need help,

I am using WAMP server for my project.
I have created a photo_gallery.php page where I am both uploading and displaying the images. When I click on Upload button after selecting images, it moves to loginform_php where I enter username & password. 
loginform.php

```
<form id='login' action='login.php' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<fieldset >
<legend>Login</legend>
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>  
<label for='username' >UserName*:</label>
<input type='text' name='username' id='username'  maxlength="10" /> 
<label for='password' >Password*:</label>
<input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="10" />  
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />   
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Next, it moves to login.php where I have implicitly stored the username and password:
Login.php

```
<?php
$usr="root";
$pwd="root";  
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
if(($username==$usr) && ($password==$pwd) )
{   
    header('Location: ./upload.php');
}
else
{
    echo '<br>login unsuccessfull';
} 
?>
```

After validation, it redirects to upload.php where it should process the upload process but unsuccessful and throws an error.
upload.php

```
$errors = array();
$uploadedFiles = array();
$extension = array("jpeg","jpg","png","gif","JPG","JPEG","GIF","PNG");
$bytes = 1024;
$KB = 100024;
$totalBytes = $bytes * $KB;
$UploadFolder = "./images";

$counter = 0;

foreach($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name)  //throws an error
{
    $temp = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];
    $name = $_FILES["files"]["name"][$key];

    if(empty($temp))
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

The error is:

[click here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN3f8.png)

PS: When I don't do validation, and directly upload the photos upon selection, the upload.php works perfectly fine and uploads the photo.

Form in photo_gallery.php

```
<form action="./loginform.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The redirect is followed by the browser making a GET request, there is no POST data available any more in your upload.php. You will have to store the POST data and files somewhere from within your login.php script, if you want to be able to access them later on in a script that has no relation to the actual upload at all.

Comment: `header('Location: ./upload.php');` - That's a brand new request, so nothing gets posted! Can't you just require in upload.php after login?

Comment: I don't know the process to do that, please help me with it.

Comment: @delboy1978uk   No idea about require method.

Comment: @CBroe How can I store the POST data so that it can be processed by upload.php

Comment: try just `require_once('/path/to/upload.php')`.

Comment: However, why are you letting non logged in users upload? Make them log in first and this problem disappears!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you redirect from one post form to another post form then previous post/get variables will be cleared.

When you reach to login.php in form submit by post/get then your previous page post variables($_POST,$_FILES,etc..)will be cleared. By redirecting from login.php to upload.php will send empty $_FILES object. 
you can save your $_FILES object in one session variable before redirecting to login.php (after validation) then you can access this in upload.php with session variable, when it reached through login.php file.

Comment: in which page should I store the session-variable as I am confused by **after validation**

Comment: you have to store in session variable before redirecting to the  header('Location: ./login.php');

Comment: So, that must be in `loginform.php`.

Comment: I need to use session variable in just one page or more?

Comment: you have to save the session variable and then in upload.php you have to fetch $_FILES from $_SESSION.  if(empty($_SESSION)) $filedata=$_FILES; else $filedata=$_SESSION;  foreach($filedata as $x) instead of $_FILES and also clear $_SESSION after entering into foreach loop.